# Compressing textures

Tags: texturing

Apart from ticking the Compress box, what would be the best method of compressing my textures? Without them, my file is about 6Mb, with them, I've got it down to 16Mb. I have three textures I made in Photoshop that are 6.18Mb, 1.46Mb and 4.08Mb. How could I go about compressing them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about using blender.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is save space to transfer the file, you can try a couple things.

- Compress the blend file with textures (zip, xz, etc)
- Create a tarball with your textures, and use compression across multiple files. This takes advantage of the fact that textures contain very redundant information.

If you need to save space and still want everything to work normally, your only option is to really use lower-res textures. Although you could probably use a lossy format like jpeg as opposed to png another lossless compression algorithm if you're okay with some quality loss.

Answer (score 0):

save them as jpg and set quality to 5 in Photoshop while saving :)

Comment: Is this about Blender at all?